# Disable Navigation in DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

How would I disable the navigation within a DataGridView?
I am unsure of as to why this is as all properties have been 'disabled' or turned to false.

Comment: you need to provide more information.do you want to disable the page-navigation? do you want to disable selection of rows?

Comment: The only functionality I need form the DataGridView is for the user to  click on rows only, with no key navigation. The essentially the user clicks on a record, and the related text boxes are updated.

Comment: You can set the SelectionMode property of the DataGridView to be "FullRowSelect", is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property on the DataGridView called "SelectionMode" that you can set to "FullRowSelect" which only allows the user to select rows.